# How to get list of files in some folder of my war file?

Tags: java, spring

I have a Java project (Spring). I need to get list of images from folder "images" and randomly choose one of them. I have a problem with getting list of files from a this directory in my war file. What class can I use for it? And how I can set a path to my folder?
Thank you for your help help!

P.S. I use a service (not Controller) which should give me a name of random image from my images folder? It looks like:

```
<body style="background: url(request.getContextPath() + RandomBackgroundService.getRandomBackground()) ...
```

How my Service will look?

Comment: Where are you trying to access the files? From a jsp file or from a Java class?

Comment: @keaplogik from Java class.
I made a service that returns a random name of background image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the list from [ServletContext.getResourcePaths()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourcePaths%28java.lang.String%29) - just autowire a reference into your controller and ask for the correct folder-

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/whatever")
public class MyClass {

    @Autowired
    private final ServletContext context;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get(ModelMap model) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        List<String> images = new ArrayList<String>(context.getResourcePaths("/images"));
        model.addAttribute("randomImage", images.get(rand.nextInt(images.size())));
        return "myPage";
    }

}
```

Comment: but if I use a service (not Controller) which should give me a name of random image from my images folder?

It looks like:
`<body style="background: url(request.getContextPath() + RandomBackgroundService.getRandomBackground()) ...
`
How my Service will look?

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, ignore the "target" directory. It is just where maven places the results of it's processing.

If you need to retrieve data from a WAR file directory in runtime, I would use something like:

```
for (String s : req.getServletContext().getResourcePaths("images")) {
    InputStream resource = req.getServletContext.getResourceAsStream(s);
    // do something with resource
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access the images directory from a class this should work:

```
File imagesFolder = MyClass.getResource("images").getFile();
for (File image : imagesFolder.listFiles()) {
    // TODO: Figure out your random logic.
}
```

Reading the documentation on `Class.getResource()` may also help you when determine how to access resources within an application.